# Class and external method call

Tags: python

I am going through a data structures course and I am not understanding how a Class can call a method that's in another Class.
The code below has 2 classes: `Printer` and `Task`.
Notice that class `Printer` has a method called `startNext`, and this has a variable `self.timeRemaining` that gets assigned the result of `newTask.getPages() * 60/self.pagerate`.

How can `newTaks` reference the `getPages()` method from the Task class?
The code that passes this object to the Printer class never references the Task class.
The code works, since this is what the course gives out but, I just cannot understand how that method is accessed.
Code:

```
from pythonds.basic.queue import Queue

import random

class Printer:

    def __init__(self, ppm):
        self.pagerate = ppm
        self.currentTask = None
        self.timeRemaining = 0

    def tick(self):
        if self.currentTask != None:
            self.timeRemaining = self.timeRemaining - 1

            if self.timeRemaining <= 0:
                self.currentTask = None

    def busy(self):
        if self.currentTask != None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def startNext(self, newTask):
        self.currentTask = newTask
        self.timeRemaining = newTask.getPages() * 60/self.pagerate

class Task:

    def __init__(self, time):
        self.timeStamp = time
        self.pages = random.randrange(1, 21)

    def getStamp(self):
        return self.timeStamp

    def getPages(self):
        return self.pages

    def waitTime(self, currentTime):
        return currentTime - self.timeStamp

def simulation(numSeconds, pagesPerMinute):

    labPrinter = Printer(pagesPerMinute)
    printQueue = Queue()
    waitingTimes = []

    for currentSecond in range(numSeconds):

        if newPrintTask():
            task = Task(currentSecond)
            printQueue.enqueue(task)

        if (not labPrinter.busy()) and (not printQueue.isEmpty()):
            nextTask = printQueue.dequeue()
            waitingTimes.append(nextTask.waitTime(currentSecond))
            labPrinter.startNext(nextTask)

        labPrinter.tick()

    averageWait = sum(waitingTimes)/len(waitingTimes)
    print "Average Wait %6.2f secs %3d tasks remaining." % (averageWait, printQueue.size())

def newPrintTask():
    num = random.randrange(1, 181)

    if num == 180:
        return True
    else:
        return False

for i in range(10):
    simulation(3600, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks, your comment was everything but helpful in solving my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand clearly your question, it is because you are adding task object to Queue list. Then when you are getting object (list item) back, you are getting again Task object:

```
#creating Task object and adding to Queque list
task = Task(currentSecond)
printQueue.enqueue(task)

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        #list of task objects
        self.items = []

    def enqueue(self, item):
        #you are inserting Task object item to list
        self.items.insert(0,item)

    def dequeue(self):
       #returns task object
       return self.items.pop()
```

So then you can call startNext() method from Printer class, because the dequeue() method is returning Task object.

And because of the object in startNext() is type of Task, you can call getPages() method on that object.

Is it sufficient answer?

Comment: Thanks for responding. But my question is related to when this variable calls startNext: labPrinter.startNext(nextTask). If you notice, labPrinter is an instance of class Printer, and it never references the Task Class, so how can it call the startNext method?

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you want reference labPrinter to Task Class?  startNext() is instance method of Printer Class, you are calling it via labPrinter instance.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my original post, this is code from a book I'm reading and I just wanted to make sense of it. From what you are telling me, the code is wrong?

Comment: No I think the code is good. And you said code works. You can post example how you want reference the Task Class. I will edited my answer, we don't understand good to each other probably.